# How do I left align text in a menu and keep the text visible?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

I want to left align text in a drop-down menu but I'm having some problems.  I have this HTML

```
 <nav>
       <a>Vote</a>
       <a>Search</a>
       <a>About</a>
 </nav>
```

and this CSS for the drop down menu

```
nav {
  display: none;
  width: 30rem;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-open {
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.4rem 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000;
}
```

But as you can see, when you click the menu icon the text isn't even visible.  Interestingly, when I change:

```
text-align: left;
```

to

```
text-align: center;
```

I can see the text again, but it is not aligned where i want it.  How do I left align my text and keep it visible?

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

```css
style* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Benton Sans, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#pageTitle {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

#pageTitle h2 {
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-btn div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-top: -0.50em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 200;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background: #989da1;
  z-index: 99;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  width: 30rem;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-open {
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.4rem 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <div id="pageTitle">
    <h2>Page Title</h2>

    <div class="mobile-nav">

      <button class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
     </button>

      <nav>
        <a>Vote</a>
        <a>Search</a>
        <a>About</a>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your text appears visible for me when aligned to the left; I cannot replicate your problem. Have you confirmed that it still exists? Are you sure you haven't just got a narrow window where the text is pushed off the screen?

Comment: Make your window bigger so you can see where the text is

Comment: I see no problem, even when full page

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO problem comes when window is small(mobile)

Comment: @ObsidianAge this is a mobile issue, smaller window will reveal the issue

Comment: The main issue is that your nav is `30rem` which results in a bigger than needed nav on mobile, so your text is on the left side and you can't see on smaller screens. Change the nav width to 100% for mobile and it will be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the rem unit you are using when giving `width` to your nav. You should use `vw` viewport width. This is relative from the screen width going from 0 to 100 turning the viewport width into a percentage.

Hope this helps

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

```css
style* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Benton Sans, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#pageTitle {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

#pageTitle h2 {
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-btn div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin-top: -0.50em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 200;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background: #989da1;
  z-index: 99;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-open {
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.4rem 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <div id="pageTitle">
    <h2>Page Title</h2>

    <div class="mobile-nav">

      <button class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
     </button>

      <nav>
        <a>Vote</a>
        <a>Search</a>
        <a>About</a>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I think 100vw or 100% is what OP wants since the entire menu was covering left to right and OP was not able to see the text

Comment: @Huangism could be.Edited, Thank

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out already, the text is actually aligned left, but your screen size might prevent it from showing up due to the big width of your menu.
Try changing the `width` of your `nav` element to something relative to the page width, like `80%`:

```
nav {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1y8n08aq/1/